# Why does Google Chrome flag my application as Malware?

Tags: google-chrome, malware

I have an application which I made in VS 2010 in C#-4.0.

The purpose of the program is to handle product orders for my employer.

However, for some reason, and this is the only program that I've seen do this, when it is available for download, Google Chrome flags it as Malware and blocks the download.

Why would this be happening, and is there any way to correct the issue?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the exact message that Chrome provides? I'd be somewhat surprised if it's flagging it as malware and you're sure it's not; Chrome *also* has a warning if it is not a commonly-downloaded program, which I suspect you might be getting.

Answer (score -1):

There are instructions here for a few things to check, and then you can resubmit your application for review:

Things to check before review:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249?hl=en&ref_topic=2365140

Submit for review:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/168328

Comment: Understood, I will do that from this point forward.  I have reviewed the article that you linked and will follow those instructions.